# query 2 vertexes orientdb

Tags: orientdb, vertex

I have 2 vertexes, `Client` and `Campaign`, linked by an edge `hasClient`.

Schema: `Client #33` ----- `hasClient #19` ----- `Campaign #15`

I would like to have the name of the client and also the number of edge he has with Campaign (generally more than 1).

Do you know how to query this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
select name,out("hasClient").size() as size from Client
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thank's for the answer ! It displays the name and an "out" column full of []... So it doesn't work. Do you have an other idea ? Or maybe I can have the length of those arrays even if they seem empty.